# Working with openFrameworks in Qt-Creator

Tags: qt-creator, openframeworks

How can I use OF within Qt Creator environment?
I fact , how should I build the lib and add it in my .pro file and all.

Comment: is this post referring to www.openframeworks.cc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully done a porting of open frameworks project in creator loading plain Makefile projects.

You can add the includes directory in the file `projectName.includes` to have auto-completition and file navigation (just do it with a `find` shell command against `OF_PATH/libs`) and it is very handy.

Moreover config.make and addons.make let you use the builtin project-creation tools and workflow provided by the official community project management system, and also add external binary/libraries/shared components with the standard gcc command (`-I` for example).

In this way you can use QtCreator and do not care about .pro/.pri files and use the makefile projects (I have tested it both on linux and mac/osx) and I think there will be no problem also with arch compiling.

Also no problem with C++11 (even if I haven't tested all new features of the language).

See this post in the [official forum.](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/openframeworks-project-files-for-qtcreator-qmake/14106/3)

Comment: Is it still worth to learn openframework in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this github repository: https://github.com/procedural/ofqmake There is a qmake project file (.pro) if you want to build openFrameworks using qtcreator as well as a qmake include file (.pri) if you want to use oF in your own projects.

This is exactly what you want to do. Get the [openFrameworks.pri](https://github.com/procedural/ofqmake/blob/master/linux/openFrameworks.pri) file and include it in your .pro file by adding `include(openFrameworks.pri)`.

Answer (score 1):

Qt itself provide an open-framework called [Qt-Complex](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aTools%3a%3aQtComplex). Go through it and you can find how to add a framework to your project there.

Comment: i think you're confusing the specific library "openFrameworks" with the generic term "open framework"

Answer (score 0):

To update this topic again, since OF9.0, QT Creator is now officially supported *(and even the default recommended IDE!)*.
See this setup Guide: http://openframeworks.cc/setup/qtcreator/